# Add auto increment to already existing primary key column PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, auto-increment

I have a database schema of the following table:

```
database=# \d person
              Table "public.person"
   Column    |         Type          | Modifiers
-------------+-----------------------+-----------
 person_id   | smallint              | not null
 fname       | character varying(20) |
 lname       | character varying(20) |
 eye_color   | color_enum            |
 birth_date  | date                  |
 street      | character varying(30) |
 city        | character varying(20) |
 state       | character varying(20) |
 country     | character varying(20) |
 postal_code | character varying(20) |
```

I want to add `AUTO_INCREMENT` in one `ALTER` statement the way we can do in MySQL

```
ALTER TABLE person MODIFY person_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

I have tried this in Postgres but I am getting this error:

```
ALTER TABLE person ALTER COLUMN person_id SERIAL;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SERIAL"
```

I have seen we can create a **sequence** in the following fashion

```
ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq OWNED BY tablename.colname;
CREATE SEQUENCE test_id_seq OWNED BY test1.id;
ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('test_id_seq');
  UPDATE test1 SET id = nextval('test_id_seq');
```

But this is too much boilerplate code. Is there a one-line statement to add `AUTO_INCREMENT` to an existing column in Postgres?

Postgres Version: 9.6.16

## Update

After doing the boilerplate code, I am trying to INSERT using the following query:

```sql
 INSERT INTO person
 (person_id, fname, lname, eye_color, birth_date)
 VALUES (null, 'William','Turner', 'BR', '1972-05-27');

ERROR:  null value in column "person_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, William, Turner, BR, 1972-05-27, null, null, null, null, null).
```

Is there a workaround by which I can pass null values to the primary key where the value of that column is from the sequence?

## Answer

Was able to insert using the following error:

```
INSERT INTO person(person_id, fname, lname, eye_color, birth_date)
       VALUES (nextval('person_id_seq'), 'William','Turner', 'BR', '1972-05-27');
```

Comment: If you were using a more up-to-date Postgres version, you could simply run `alter table person alter person_id add generated always as identity;` and then adjust all sequences in a single go like e.g. this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62060505

Comment: Your INSERT explicitly specifies a NULL value for `person_id` - obviously you'll get a constraint violation. To "trigger" the default value, don't specify the column at all

Comment: I was able to insert using the query `INSERT INTO person(person_id, fname, lname,eye_color, birth_date) VALUES (nextval('person_id_seq'), 'William','Turner', 'BR', '1972-05-27');`

Comment: Please do **not** run an UPDATE to "synchronize" the sequence with the data. And you should also run `alter sequence ... owned by ...`. Btw: your "answer" answers a different question than "how do I make a column a serial?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is too much boilerplate code, then create a function that does the job:

```
create or replace function make_serial(p_table_schema text, p_table_name text, p_column_name text)
  returns void
as
$$
declare
  l_sql text;
  l_seq_name text;
  l_full_name text;
begin
  l_seq_name := concat(p_table_name, '_', p_column_name, '_seq');
  l_full_name := quote_ident(p_table_schema)||'.'||quote_ident(l_seq_name);
  
  execute format('create sequence %I.%I', p_table_schema, l_seq_name);
  execute format('alter table %I.%I alter column %I set default nextval(%L)', p_table_schema, p_table_name, p_column_name, l_seq_name);
  execute format('alter table %I.%I alter column %I set not null', p_table_schema, p_table_name, p_column_name);
  execute format('alter sequence %I.%I owned by %I.%I', p_table_schema, l_seq_name, p_table_name, p_column_name);
  execute format('select setval(%L, coalesce(max(%I),0)) from %I', l_full_name, p_column_name, p_table_name);
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

You can remove the `set not null` statement if you know that all your columns are already defined as `NOT NULL`.

To synchronize the sequence with the existing values, the above code essentially runs:

```
select setval('person_id_seq', max(person_id))
from person;
```

(Updating all rows and possibly changing their primary key values is the wrong approach to sync the sequence).

Then to change a table, all you need to do is:

```
select make_serial('public', 'person', 'person_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. Before insert trigger to set person_id column with some sequence.
2. Set default value to sequence next value. Example is below.

   ```
   create table t1 (id int primary key , x int);

   insert into t1 values (1,1);

   create sequence t1_Seq start with 2;

   alter table t1 alter column id set  default nextval('t1_seq');

   insert into t1 (x) values (2);
   ```